# User-defined mode not supported

Tags: debian, wayland, drm

I'm trying to get my NanoPI R5S, which is running a [custom Debian build](https://github.com/inindev/nanopi-r5/releases/tag/v12.0.3), to run Wayfire at the connected monitor's native resolution (3440x1440@60).  When Wayfire attempts to display, it crashes with the following error message:

```
wayfire: ../src/core/output-layout.cpp:1540: wf::output_t* wf::output_layout_t::impl::get_output_coords_at(const wf::pointf_t&, wf::pointf_t&): Assertion `handle || is_shutting_down()' failed.
EE 17-12-23 22:25:48.596 - [src/main.cpp:141] Fatal error: Fatal error(SIGABRT)
EE 17-12-23 22:25:48.634 - #1  wf::print_trace(bool) ??:?
addr2line: '<AC>,ڑ<FF><FF>': No such file
addr2line: '<AC>,ڑ<FF><FF>': No such file
EE 17-12-23 22:25:48.654 - #2  H<CA>4<D8><FF><FF> H<CA>4<D8><FF><FF>
EE 17-12-23 22:25:48.682 - #3  pthread_key_delete ??:?
EE 17-12-23 22:25:48.710 - #4  gsignal ??:?
EE 17-12-23 22:25:48.739 - #5  abort ??:?
EE 17-12-23 22:25:48.767 - #6  uselocale ??:?
EE 17-12-23 22:25:48.802 - #7  __assert_fail ??:?
EE 17-12-23 22:25:48.838 - #8  std::_Function_base::~_Function_base() ??:?
EE 17-12-23 22:25:48.875 - #9  wf::output_layout_t::get_output_at(int, int) ??:?
EE 17-12-23 22:25:48.912 - #10 wf::compositor_core_impl_t::post_init() ??:?
EE 17-12-23 22:25:48.950 - #11 main ??:?
EE 17-12-23 22:25:48.982 - #12 __libc_init_first ??:?
EE 17-12-23 22:25:49.013 - #13 __libc_start_main ??:?
EE 17-12-23 22:25:49.051 - #14 _start ??:?
```

The kernel logs also report:

```
[Sun Dec 17 22:25:50 2023] rockchip-drm display-subsystem: [drm] User-defined mode not supported: "3440x1440": 60 319750 3440 3488 3520 3600 1440 1443 1453 1481 0x68 0x9
```

The EDID reports:

```
  Detailed Timing Descriptors:
    DTD 1:  3440x1440   59.972616 Hz  43:18    88.819 kHz    319.750000 MHz (800 mm x 335 mm)
                 Hfront   48 Hsync  32 Hback   80 Hpol P
                 Vfront    3 Vsync  10 Vback   28 Vpol N
```

I'm unsure of the best path forward.  I suspect something in the `rockchip-drm` needs to be updated to support the unexpected resolution.